# Is it possible to install software from the Mac Appstore on a SD Card or an external HDD?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'm using a Macbook Air. The internal SSD with only 128 GB is nearly full. I already moved my pictures and music to a SD-Card (Transcend JetDrive). No I'm wondering, if it is possible to install also software on the SD Card?

Thanks for your help,
Stefan

Comment: This is probably a better fit for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan,

Installed software for mac is easily moved by going into applications folder and lifting the whole folder/application to the destination. More advanced methods include a **dd** in console command that actually coppies the bits to the device. I would try my hand at a Debian Raspberry pie install to get a hang of it.

Comment: That was to easy ;-). Thanks for your help